# Uber oauth api throws error for json object passed as 'state' param during authorize step

Tags: oauth-2.0, uber-api

Uber oauth api throws "invalid request parameters" errors, if passed json objects for 'state' parameter during 'authorize' step. [Uber oauth2 doc](https://developer.uber.com/v1/auth/#oauth-2-0).

My authorize url look something like this:-

```
https://login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?scope=profile+history_lite+request&state=%7B%27callback%27%3A+%27amazing_token_callback%27%2C+%27lib_id%27%3A+%27uber%27%2C+%27host%27%3A+%27http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.5%3A8080%2F%27%7D&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.myamazinguber.com%2Ftoken&response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If I change 'state' value to '{}', it still throws error. It doesn't throw error for non json string object.

My question is there any sort of limitations for what can be passed as 'state' parameter in authorize step.

Comment: Did you successfully login? I'm stuck with the 3rd part of login where I make a request with the authorization code to get the access token. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @AnupamBasak It seems uber api has problems handling special characters including brackets.